# AdMod Set up I'm soooo close I just need a little assistance

Tags: android, cordova, admob, banner

The app looks great but still no ads. I have 13 requests and 100% fill rate so I know its sending but I can't get any to show up. I redesigned the app and kept it simple a few divs and buttons. I'm hoping I just have something out of place or maybe you have a better (Still Simple) way of doing it. I need to get this working for 3 more apps. Your expertise is greatly appreciated thank you.

MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.appsclamation.wowmedesigns"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<meta-data android:value="true" android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".DefaultActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <activity 
   android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|
  screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

MAIN:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

   <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    ads:adUnitId="My_ID"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance...

DefaultActivity: (Source Code?)

```
 package com.appsclamation.wowmedesigns;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.phonegap.*;

public class DefaultActivity extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty( "splashscreen", R.drawable.splash );
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 1000);
    }
}
```

I was under the impression that if you use the LoadonCreate in the MAIN you did not need to do anything else.

Comment: Best thing to do is wait. I have heard, it takes hours for ads to show in application.

Comment: Can you include the source code where you showing the admob view?

Comment: you need to pass addid to show up

Comment: Ok I guess I'm not as close as I thought. I followed the tutorial but I'm not sure what other codes I need to place. Wow!!! Sorry where do I find source code and Java code? I will gladly get them for you.

Comment: It's been 4 days and I see 13 requests and the light is green so I'm thinking it's on my end.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this in your mainactivity:

```
Adview adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

In your manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

In layout used in your mainactivity:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/ADMOB_PublisherId"
                ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

where ADMOB_PublisherId would be your ID generated after registering your application

Comment: Okay I will try this, the only thing I'm not sure of is where to place the Activity code. I know where the code is I mean where in the code? I get errors every time. Between where and where?

Comment: Also do I leave the @srting/ in with my ID or just my ID because I'm getting and error? And placing the Adview code in my DefaultActivity and getting and error I'm sure I'm just not placing it correctly. Everything else look pretty much the same.

Comment: Okay I'm just mucking up the code trying to understand what you mean by "I need to do this" I'm better at visuals so is anyone willing to do that? I'm not a dummy, I do have some coding skills but I'm just not getting what you're saying. Put what where is all I need. My code is above I tried what I thought you meant NightCrawler but I'm getting errors with it. Please someone show me what I've done wrong above or what other information you need to help me help myself.

Comment: Okay I've been working hard and I finally got it to show. It was the MainActivity adView. Once I got it in there and errors out it started to show. much appreciated.